# How to create a dynamic range & skip blank cells in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently trying to create an embedded graph on my worksheet labelled "Unit2SelectedData." The problem that is occurring is when I create the graph from the ranges, it doesn't skip the cells with the value #N/A/Blank so the legend/values are off.

I tried changing the cell values to #N/A and when I manually create the graph it works and skips the #N/A values. But when automating it with VBA it does not.

So far I tried .DisplayBlanksAs = xlNotPlotted and Cells.Replace "#N/A", vbNullString and it did not seem to do the trick. I also tried changing the values from #N/A or =NA() to completely blank. Help would be appreciated!

I realized the main problem is the way I set my ranges to get data for the graph. I am currently using  `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)` 
to only get constant values from a large range which i have set to cells 10:500. 
If I removed this and create the graph I skip the blank cells and the graph looks like the series values in the desired example below. But, if not all those rows are populated with data the graph has a ton of empty columns/series and it makes the graph look bad. 
For example if I create the graph with only 5 rows populated with data, then there would be 495 extra blank points on the graph. (You can see in the code below in the 'Chart Selected Data' block.)
How do I alter my code to fix this? / Create a range that selects the last row with data?

```
Sub GraphUnit2()

    'Variables Declaration
    'Range
     Dim dataRange As Range
    'Range 1
     Dim dataRange1 As Range
    'Range 2
     Dim dataRange2 As Range
    'Range 3
    Dim dataRange3 As Range
    'Range 4
    Dim dataRange4 As Range
    'Range 5
    Dim dataRange5 As Range
    'Range 6
    Dim dataRange6 As Range
    'Range 7
    Dim dataRange7 As Range
    'Range 8 (Dates + Time)
    Dim dataRange8 As Range


    'Chart Selected Data
    'Range
        Set dataRange = Sheets("Unit2SelectedData").Range("J10:J500").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    'Range 1
        Set dataRange1 = Sheets("Unit2SelectedData").Range("C10:C500").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    'Range 2
        Set dataRange2 = Sheets("Unit2SelectedData").Range("D10:D500").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    'Range 3
        Set dataRange3 = Sheets("Unit2SelectedData").Range("E10:E500").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    'Range 4
        Set dataRange4 = Sheets("Unit2SelectedData").Range("F10:F500").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    'Range 5
        Set dataRange5 = Sheets("Unit2SelectedData").Range("G10:G500").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    'Range 6
        Set dataRange6 = Sheets("Unit2SelectedData").Range("H10:H500").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    'Range 7
        Set dataRange7 = Sheets("Unit2SelectedData").Range("I10:I500").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    'Range 8
        Set dataRange8 = Sheets("Unit2SelectedData").Range("A10:B500").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)

    'Chart Location/ Coordinates
    Sheets("Unit2SelectedData").ChartObjects.Add Left:=900, Top:=50, Width:=800, Height:=400
    Sheets("Unit2SelectedData").ChartObjects(1).Activate


    With ActiveChart      'Set chart properties

        .ChartType = xlLineMarkers
        .ApplyLayout Layout:=5
        .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .HasLegend = True
        .Legend.Position = xlRight
        .Axes(xlCategory).MinorTickMark = xlOutside
        .Axes(xlValue).MinorTickMark = xlOutside
        .Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(dataRange), -1)
        .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
        'X axis label
        .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Date/Time"
        .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
        .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Place"
        .SeriesCollection(1).Name = "PlaceHolder"
        .SeriesCollection(1).Values = dataRange
        .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = dataRange8
        .ChartTitle.Text = "Place Holder"
        End With


    'Data Series for Range 1

    With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    .Values = dataRange1
    .Name = Sheets("Unit2SelectedData").Range("C3")
    End With

    'Data Series for Range 2
         With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .Values = dataRange2
        .Name = Sheets("Unit2SelectedData").Range("D3")
        End With

    'Data Series for Range 3
        With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
            .Values = dataRange3
            .Name = Sheets("Unit2SelectedData").Range("E3")
        End With


    'Data Series for Range 4
    With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
            .Values = dataRange4
            .Name = Sheets("Unit2SelectedData").Range("F3")
        End With


    'Data Series for Range 5
        With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .Values = dataRange5
        .Name = Sheets("Unit2SelectedData").Range("G3")
    End With

    'Data Series for Range 6
    With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .Values = dataRange6
        .Name = Sheets("Unit2SelectedData").Range("H3")
    End With

    'Data Series for Range 7
    With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .Values = dataRange7
        .Name = Sheets("Unit2SelectedData").Range("I3")
    End With

End Sub
```

Example of the Data:

```
    Date        Value 1    Value 2  Value 3  Value 4  Value 5.... etc 
    11/07/2019     1         2         3        4        5
    12/07/2019     #N/A     #N/A       4        5       #N/A
    13/07/2019     3         4       #N/A       6        7
    14/07/2019     4         5         6        7        8
```

When I print the graph the value 1 series. It would be

```
    July 11 1 
    July 12 3 
    July 13 4 
    July 14 0/blank
```

Where ideally I want it to be

```
    July 11 1 
    July 12 Blank/0/Skip on the graph  
    July 13 3 
    July 14 4
```

As you can see theres a ton of blank spaces when I set the range from J10:J40 and other ranges to 10:40. For now, all these cells aren't filled with data, but they potentially will be. 
[image: Link to graph]

This is what I want the graph to look like. 
[image: Link to desired graph]

Option 2 graph
[image: Link to option 2 graph]

Comment: Try the method for Excel 2007 [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/884406/a-line-chart-may-plot-gaps-in-lines-when-the-data-range-contains-blank)

Comment: Hi, 

This does work if I am manually selecting the ranges to create the graphs, and I have tried this before. But, I am trying to create the graphs using VBA code within excel and this doesn't help too much. Thank you though.

Comment: What's the difference between two graphs? Missing values within the range are being sorted out. Also set your chart properties after you have added all the series.

Comment: The main issue with the 2 graphs. For the first graph I set the range to J10:J40 + other data ranges. 

While the second graph is just set to J10:J28 + other data ranges for the extent of the data. 

I have another form in which the user enters a date range and it pulls all the data between those 2 dates from a data table. 

So this would have to graph more than J:10 to J:28 (Graph 2) if the date range is higher. If i set the ranges to 500, everything it would look like graph 3? If that makes sense.

Comment: With option 1, blank cells in the used range are interpolated, and so your graph has all the points connected, which was your original question, as July 12 is skipped. The first 2 graphs are essentially the same, with the exception of the blanks **AT THE END** of the series data (hence no inter/extrapolation). Since all those rows are blank, why plot them in the first case? If a user selects an end date for which there is **NO** data at all, why not use `.End(xlUp)` to set the true plot range's end?

Answer (score 0):

First, **STOP** using `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)` ranges. Use the normal ranges e.g. `Range("J10:J500")`.

**Solution**: Use chart properties to interpolate or connect lines over missing values.  To do this, add the following line for each chart, replacing `ActiveChart` or chart variable or name:

```
ActiveChart.DisplayBlanksAs = xlInterpolated
```

Comment: Hey, 

I added the line ```ActiveChart.DisplayBlanksAs = xlInterpolated ``` within my chart properties 


and I removed ```.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants) ``` from the ranges 

I will update the post with a picture of the graph, since it will be easier to explain. I changed the ranges from J10:J40 just for this example.